# Alias for some code without CREATE FUNCTION?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that makes repeated use of the same snippet of code, which I'll call `foo()`, as if the function existed:

```
SELECT
    foo(a),
    BUILTIN(foo(a))
FROM 
    foobar
GROUP BY
    foo(a)
HAVING
    BUILTIN(foo(a)) > bar()
ORDER BY
    foo(a)
;
```

Usually, I would have created this function `foo` long ago - what I actually see in my editor is the same messy nest of built-in functions several times.

However - I cannot `CREATE` my nice `foo`, as I only have `USAGE` permissions.

Does there exist a way for me to create some kind of 'alias', such that whenever *I* say `foo`, a longer function is executed; but this would of course not be available to any other DB user?

Comment: the whole point of functions is to encapsulate code in a nice simple syntax. since you can't define functions, you'll just have to repeat your function's code everywhere.

Comment: @MarcB I know that's the whole point. That's what I want to use one for! I wondered if there was a way for psql to 'know' locally that when I say `foo` I want `bar` to happen - but crucially `foo` is not `create`d server-side, since I do not have permission to do so.

Comment: I believe you can create a function in the `pg_temp` schema and it will disappear after the connection closes, but I couldn't tell you if you have access to that or not.

Comment: nope. you need functions, there's no other workaround. it'd be a pretty silly DB security system that restricts function creation, but has a completely identical "this_is_not_a_function" syntax that is allowed.

Comment: @MarcB Well, the point would be at DB side it's exactly the same - noone else could see/use it, I wouldn't be creating anything there. I could go overkill and write a function to replace `foo` with whatever and then run the query in any scripting language - that's not a flaw of anyone's security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of the example you posted compute `foo(a)` in a subquery:

```
select foo_a, builtin(foo_a)
from (
    select foo(a) as foo_a
    from foobar
) s
group by 1
having builtin(foo_a) > bar()
order by 1
;
```

Comment: I've accepted this answer because it's probably best in the general case, although I'd actually arrived at my code by trying to remove sub-queries. In my case, creating the function in `pg_temp` schema as BaconBits suggested worked a treat.